# How many species of mites live on the human body?

Tags: human-biology, entomology, arachnology

**How many known species of mites regularly live on the human body?**

I've always heard that most people have eyebrow mites. [This source](http://insects.about.com/od/ticksmites/f/Do-We-Really-Have-Bugs-Living-In-Our-Eyebrows.htm)  mentions 2 species of face mites, *Demodex folliculorum* and *D. brevis*,  that also regularly live on humans, but I'm wondering if there are in fact other species of mites that also call human bodies home. **If so, how many? And where do they live?**

Note: I'm not talking about *disruptive* mites such as scabies,  but mites that go less detected.

Comment: Mites like all living things require an energy source. Demodex and lice are parasite. Other mites can be ectoparasites but are not permanent residents of the human body

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 2-3 human mites.

This page says that 2 mites specialize on humans: 
http://www.bbc.com/earth/story/20150508-these-mites-live-on-your-face
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10493-009-9272-0

Another page I found said there are 3 common human mites, adding scabies to the list.

This page talks about bites from a variety of dust and house mites: 
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10493-009-9272-0

My biology lecturer from university of Edinburgh told us that we have hundreds of species of detrital nematodes living on and inside us and that nematodes can be a few microns long. About 800 million humans have a 30cm large nematode inside them according to the WHO.