# What kind of mite is this?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

I found this (mite?) on my head skin close to hair. Is it a common dust mite or something else? Photographs under a simple microscope (10x objective) are below. Size is in the order of tenths of mm. Some of the hair sticking out are as long as the body. It was not that translucent enough to be well visible in bright field, only as a black spot.

Also, what could be the large round white object on the back an the brown spot to the left and right in the first picture?

[image: body one side]
[image: body the other side]

Note: One month ago I was treated for scabies and my head is still itching (although scabies is supposed to not affect heads of adults). But I do not think this is Sarcoptes and I think it likely does not cause the itching.

Comment: related: [How many species of mites live on the human body?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/43650/how-many-species-of-mites-live-on-the-human-body)